# How do I get wireless usb adapter TL-WN727N working in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, usb, package-management

annyone knows how to get the drivers for TL-WN272N? Tried the command: sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-wireless-generic wich didnt work (didnt find the package).

the info from lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter

Comment: Please run the terminal command: lsusb and edit your question to add your wireless card details.

Comment: Ok, this is what it returned!

Answer (score 0):

Please see posts #2 and #4 here:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1800178&highlight=rt5370sta The location of the file has changed to here; see RT8070 /RT3070 /RT3370 /RT5370 /RT5372 USB:  http://www.ralinktech.com/en/04_support/support.php?sn=501

Or you could upgrade to 12.10 where is is supported by default with rt2800usb.